# align first two elements in the unordered list items inline and the rest one per line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this list which I am trying to arrange.

I want to show the first two `<li>` elements in one line (inline) and other elements in separate rows.

I have tried adding display table > table-cell css properties to first two elements, but it just indents the other `<li>` elements to second row.

Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

```
<ul>
  <li> Check All </li>
  <li> Uncheck All </li>
  <li> Option A </li>
  <li> Option B </li>
  <li> Option C </li>
  <li> Option D </li>
  <li> Option E </li>
  <li> Option F </li>
  <li> Option G </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should really use classes and not do these kinds of CSS selections because it are not semantic, try separating them into different wrappers or classes. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a `display: inline-block` for the first two list-items, e.g.

```
li:nth-child(-n + 2) {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

As a general solution: if you need to match the first `k` list-items, the selector has to be written in the form of `li:nth-child(-n + k)`

> [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEzZOQ)

---

As a side note, if using a negative index is not intuitive to you, you can also revert the logic and apply that property to the elements that are *not* `:nth-child(n + k + 1)`, like so

```
li:not(:nth-child(n + 3)) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but in my opinion is less readable and the logic is quite convoluted.

Comment: yes, this saves you from targeting every single list-items up to `k`. You can also use negative values and chain another `:nth-child` pseudoclass to match an inner range of elements (e.g. from list-item 3 to 5)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the first two `li` inline-block...

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:first-child,
li:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Check All</li>
  <li>Uncheck All</li>
  <li>Option A</li>
  <li>Option B</li>
  <li>Option C</li>
  <li>Option D</li>
  <li>Option E</li>
  <li>Option F</li>
  <li>Option G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful for you to learn about `:first-child` and `:nth-child(2)` selectors in some instances. Given your example, though, I would assume that you simply didn't arrange the HTML in a semantic way. "Check" and "Uncheck" are actions...not list items. See the snippet below for a more semantic version of your example.

```css
.list {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.list-header {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.list-buttons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.list-ul-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="list">
  <header class="list-header">
    <div class="list-buttons">
      <button>Check All</button>
      <button>Uncheck All</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <ul class="list-ul">
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option A </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option B </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option C </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option D </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option E </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option F </li>
    <li class="list-ul-item"> Option G </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks BDawg, thats good suggestions. Will keep that for future reference,  I however did not wrote the list like that myself, i was however trying to arrange the check/uncheck buttons of a third party library i am using (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect).

Comment: Oh no! Not much you can do about semantics when it's third party. Others' answers are definitely more applicable to your particular situation, then. Best of luck!